# How to redirect Stdout of child process to a file and exit in Go?

Tags: go, child-process

Is there a way to start a child process, redirect its Stdout to a file and exit while allowing the child process to still run and use its Stdout to write the file?

I'd like the code to be platform independent. I guess in Unix-like systems [`Cmd`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd)`.ExtraFiles` can be used for this purpose however it is not supported on Windows.

Demo app below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) == 2 {
        child()
        return
    }
    executable, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tempFile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "demo.*.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("tempFile", tempFile.Name())
    _, err = tempFile.WriteString("parent\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    command := exec.Command(executable, "child")
    command.Stdout = tempFile
    err = command.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("parent end")
}

func child() {
    fmt.Println("child start")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("child end")
}
```

writes file with content

```
parent
child start
```

Comment: You don’t need ExtraFiles, stdout is obviously being set correctly, because there’s some output in there. You need to prevent the child from being terminated, which depends on the OS and how you are executing and terminating the parent.

Comment: Thank you @JimB. Would you like to make this comment an answer?